# MojoExecutionException when generate sources cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0 java11

Tags: java, java-11, cxf-xjc-plugin

I try to generate java classes from xsd in a maven project using cxf-xjc-plugin.
But when I try to generate the sources, I have an error.

I tried to use another version of the plugin: 3.2.3 but it didn't help.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <xsdDir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/</xsdDir>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

---

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
Exit code: 1
```

Comment: I do not see in the documentation for this plugin, https://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-plugin.html, that `xsdDir` is a valid element.  I believe it should be `xsd` and that a fully qualified path must be specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For java 11, I used jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.5.0
It works.