# Maven MojoExecutionException in cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cxf, maven-plugin

This question is nearly a duplicate of [MojoExecutionException when generate sources cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0 java11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971635) with two exceptions:

1. The accepted answer in that question provides a work-around without answering the question.
2. The issue discussed in that question may have been unique to a Java 11 environment.

In an Eclipse environment, I have a Java project.  Part of the build process is to generate Java source code from an XML schema file (.XSD).  I am trying to use Apache's CXF Maven plugin to invoke the XJC process to generate the Java classes from the .XSD.  Here is my POM.XML:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mbm</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Properties</name>
    <description>Define and process program arguments</description>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <xsdOptions>
                                <xsdOption>
                                    <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/mbm/properties/schema/Properties.xsd</xsd>
                                    <packagename>com.mbm.properties.jaxb</packagename>
                                </xsdOption>
                            </xsdOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sablecc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/mbm/properties/grammar</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/gen-java</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is the output from Maven (it doesn't end well):

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties\EMBEDDED
Java version: 1.8.0_221, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: plain
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\mbmas_000\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\mbmas_000\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\mbmas_000\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\mbmas_000\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.mbm:properties:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mbm:properties:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.mbm:properties:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [generate-sources]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------< com.mbm:properties >-------------------------
[INFO] Building Properties 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.mbm:properties:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile+runtime]
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [redhat-ga-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/, default, releases), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [redhat-ga-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/, default, releases), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava (xjc)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <additionalJvmArgs>${cxf.xjc.jvmArgs}</additionalJvmArgs>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}"/>
  <fork default-value="false"/>
  <javaExecutable default-value="${java.home}/bin/java"/>
  <markerDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/cxf-xsd-plugin-markers">${cxf.markerDirectory}</markerDirectory>
  <pluginArtifacts>${plugin.artifacts}</pluginArtifacts>
  <remoteRepos default-value="${project.remotePluginRepositories}"/>
  <repoSession default-value="${repositorySystemSession}"/>
  <sourceRoot default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated/src/main/java"/>
  <xsdOptions>
    <xsdOption>
      <xsd>C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties/src/main/java/com/mbm/properties/schema/Properties.xsd</xsd>
      <packagename>com.mbm.properties.jaxb</packagename>
    </xsdOption>
  </xsdOptions>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.codehaus.mojo:sablecc-maven-plugin:2.4-SNAPSHOT:generate (default)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <outputDirectory>C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties/src/main/gen-java</outputDirectory>
  <project>${project}</project>
  <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties/src/main/java/com/mbm/properties/grammar</sourceDirectory>
  <staleMillis default-value="0">${lastModGranularityMs}</staleMillis>
  <timestampDirectory>${basedir}/target</timestampDirectory>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=126299, ConflictMarker.markTime=810400, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=49100, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1477800, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2503800, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=0, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=409299, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=8338501}
[DEBUG] com.mbm:properties:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava (xjc) @ properties ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=3369200, ConflictMarker.markTime=336300, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=42, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=744200, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=103699, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=28, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=10962100, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=41, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=430410000, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=15655300}
[DEBUG] org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:jar:3.3.0
[DEBUG]    org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]             org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-resolver:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.glassfish.jaxb:xsom:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.glassfish.jaxb:codemodel:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun.xml.dtd-parser:dtd-parser:jar:1.4.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun.istack:istack-commons-tools:jar:3.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.5:compile
[DEBUG]             org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.5:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun.xml.bind.external:relaxng-datatype:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[DEBUG]    xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.2-GA:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:jar:3.3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:4.12
[DEBUG]   Included: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-resolver:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.glassfish.jaxb:xsom:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.glassfish.jaxb:codemodel:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.xml.dtd-parser:dtd-parser:jar:1.4.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.istack:istack-commons-tools:jar:3.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.5
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.xml.bind.external:relaxng-datatype:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16
[DEBUG]   Included: xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.2-GA
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@4e25154f]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) javaExecutable = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre/bin/java
[DEBUG]   (f) markerDirectory = C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties\target\cxf-xsd-plugin-markers
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifacts = [org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:maven-plugin:3.3.0:, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile, junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile, org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1:compile, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-resolver:jar:1.0:compile, jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile, jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile, org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.3.2:compile, org.glassfish.jaxb:xsom:jar:2.3.2:compile, org.glassfish.jaxb:codemodel:jar:2.3.2:compile, com.sun.xml.bind.external:rngom:jar:2.3.2:compile, com.sun.xml.dtd-parser:dtd-parser:jar:1.4.1:compile, com.sun.istack:istack-commons-tools:jar:3.0.8:compile, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.5:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.5:compile, com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile, com.sun.xml.bind.external:relaxng-datatype:jar:2.3.2:compile, org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile, org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile, org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile, com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile, xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile, org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.2-GA:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepos = [redhat-ga-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/, default, releases), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG]   (f) repoSession = org.eclipse.aether.DefaultRepositorySystemSession@726386ed
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceRoot = C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties\target/generated/src/main/java
[DEBUG]   (s) xsd = C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties/src/main/java/com/mbm/properties/schema/Properties.xsd
[DEBUG]   (s) packagename = com.mbm.properties.jaxb
[DEBUG]   (f) xsdOptions = [org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XsdOption@69adf72c]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.mbm:properties:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties\pom.xml
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Args: [-p, com.mbm.properties.jaxb, -verbose, -encoding, null, -d, C:\Users\mbmas_000\workspace\Properties\target/generated/src/main/java, file:/C:/Users/mbmas_000/workspace/Properties/src/main/java/com/mbm/properties/schema/Properties.xsd]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.262 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-05T16:54:24-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava (xjc) on project properties: null: MojoExecutionException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava (xjc) on project properties: null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.execute(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaMojo.execute(XSDToJavaMojo.java:41)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.requireArgument(Options.java:763)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArgument(Options.java:680)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.parseArguments(Options.java:827)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.XSDToJavaRunner.run(XSDToJavaRunner.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.run(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:368)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.execute(AbstractXSDToJavaMojo.java:276)
    ... 23 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

What is causing this error?  I've tried to research this, but there just isn't that much out there about this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to a bug in version 3.3.0 of the plugin.  See https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/issues/89.

The bug has been fixed, so all that needs to be done in the POM.XML file is change the version number from 3.3.0 to 3.3.1:

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
```